# Why does Promise.all not run 2 functions asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have a node js program. I want to run 2 countdown functions asynchronously by using Promise.all. It is expected that the two functions will count down together, and the program ends within 5 seconds. But they run sequentially and the program ends within 10 seconds. How to run them asynchronously? Thank you for your help.

```js
const delayOneSecond = () => {
    let start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() - start < 1000) { }
    return;
}

const OK = true;

const func = (name, num) => {
    return new Promise(
        function (resolve, reject) {
            if (OK) {
                for(let i=1; i<=num; i++){
                    delayOneSecond();
                    console.log(`[${name}] - ${num - i}`);
                }
                resolve('OK');
            } else {
                reject(new Error('Not OK'));
            }
        });
}

Promise.all([func('xxx', 5), func('ooo', 5)])
  .then((res) => { console.log(res); })
```

Comment: There is nothing asynchronous about your code, so it runs synchronously. Promises do not make code asynchronous, they abstract the handling of the async calls into an easy to manage form. To make this run async you need to add something that is itself async in nature, i.e. an ajax call or a setTimeout, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `while` loop is a loop that keeps JavaScript busy during one second. During that time no other JavaScript code can execute, no matter what else you had planned for execution. In your case this means that the second `func('ooo', 5)` does not get launched until the first call has returned.

In practice, the callback you provide to `new Promise` should not be a blocking piece of code: it should execute relatively quickly and return. It's job is mostly to call some (low-level) API that will trigger an *asynchronous* event, to which your code will listen. At that time `resolve` can be called.

You can use the Web API for this (or some other asynchronous library's API), which gives you `setTimeout`: that function will allow you to be notified when the delay (e.g. 1 second) has passed, but still executes the rest of your code to completion (which can possibly also call `setTimeout`).

If you would resolve a promise when `setTimeout` calls its callback, then you have a useful, non-blocking implementation of `delayOneSecond`. It can then be combined easily with `await`:

```js
const delayOneSecond = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

const func = async (name, num) => {
    for(let i=1; i<=num; i++){
        await delayOneSecond();
        console.log(`[${name}] - ${num - i}`);
    }
    return "OK";
}

Promise.all([func('xxx', 5), func('ooo', 5)])
  .then((res) => { console.log(res); })
```

Although it may seem here that the execution of `func` *still* takes 5 seconds before it returns, this is actually not true. It returns when it arrives at the first `await`. It returns a promise at that time (so without any delay), and execution can continue with the second call of `func`.

The two function execution contexts get restored when their `delayOneSecond()` promises resolve, i.e. after (at least) one second. Only then their `for` loops continue... This happens one after the other: they don't run their JavaScript in parallel: one function context gets restored, does its thing until the next `await`, and then the same happens with the other function context.

Comment: For the OP: this is called a "busy wait" in case you want to google more about it.